# ThenByDescending doesn't change anything in output

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am using following code and I understand that first `OrderByDescending` sort the list in descending order but when I use `ThenByDescending(x => x % 2 == 0)` nothing happened on the result list

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         var numbers = new List<int>() { 3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 6, 2 };
    var sortedNumbers = numbers.OrderByDescending(x => x);
    foreach (int i in sortedNumbers ) 
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    var sortedNumbers1 = sortedNumbers.ThenByDescending(x => x % 2 == 0);
    foreach (int i in sortedNumbers1 ) 
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    }
}
```

but If I change my code to following the second sort start to work , or at least it shows the change in result set.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         var numbers = new List<int>() { 3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 6, 2 };
    var sortedNumbers = numbers.OrderByDescending(x => x % 2 == 0);
    foreach (int i in sortedNumbers ) 
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("*-******************");
    var sortedNumbers1 = sortedNumbers.ThenByDescending(x => x);
    foreach (int i in sortedNumbers1 ) 
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can a list of integers have more than one sort applied? Once they are ordered numerically, there is nothing left to sort.

Comment: and why in second case it shows changes but in first no change in result set .

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay 4,3,2,1 ordered by even would be 4,2,3,1. But what if you want this result: 2,4,1,3? Now you have to first sort as ascending and then by even

Comment: Maybe try sorting with pen&paper yourself both ways to understand the behavior?

Comment: `x % 2 == 0` does not define an order on the elements. It will return 0 or 1, so you will end up with two "partitions", in which the order is undefined.

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL but even in MySQL the equivalent query would return the same results. You're ordering by a unique column then trying to order by non-unique data. Since there are no duplicates produced by the first operand, the second won't have anything to work on

Comment: Howto example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nOrvQz

Comment: Perhaps these example fiddles display the difference more clearly: [fiddle 1 (even/odd last)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5PYmEC) -- [fiddle 2 (even/odd first)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dYXAAj)

Answer (score 1):

`ThenByDescending` is applied when there is a "collision" in the ordering i.e. you have elements which have the same order for the previous `(Then)OrderBy(Descending)` clauses. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending?view=net-7.0):

> Performs a **subsequent** ordering of the elements in a sequence in descending order.

`var sortedNumbers = numbers.OrderByDescending(x => x);` does not have elements with ambiguous order so `ThenByDescending(x => x % 2 == 0)` has no effect.

In the second snippet where `x => x % 2 == 0` is used for ordering first so you end up with two buckets of elements (`4, 6, 2` and `3, 7, 1, 5`) so `ThenByDescending(x => x)` is applied inside each one.

Answer (score 1):

The operator used is `ThenByDescending`, which means it's applied *in conjunction* with the original operator to order any duplicates produced by the first. Since there are no duplicates, the second condition has no effect.

In SQL the equivalent would be this, and equally ineffectual :

```
ORDER BY num DESC, IIF(num %2,1,0) DESC
```

Comment: and what will be equal in linq for order by   APDD1 asc , CGpa desc ?

Comment: That's what you already did. If `APDD1` is unique, `CGpa` won't have any result in the final order. Unless you mean how to do `ASC`, which is `OrderBy()`, without the `Descending` suffix